# iOS and Organizer: Can't read dowloaded file

Tags: ios, file

I would like to dowload on my desktop the file I created on my iOS test app, data.txt.

Once I access to the App and go through the Documents folder, select the file and click on dowload the only file format possible is the XCode boudle data.

Then, once I try to open the file with XCode it shows a dulle "App Data" and I can't see the content. I tried opening it with TextEdit but no luck..

Any help?

Here is what I see:

[image: data after download]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know this [iexplorere](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) . With, you can copy all files from your device

Comment: Can't believe it, this is awsome! Thank u very much :). I really dislike Apple's policy in making things so hard to access.. and I am surprised that this software exist as I thought Apple would ban them somehow. thanks!